# 5-dimensional vector declaration

Tags: c++, vector, multidimensional-array

I am looking for an elegant way to declare a 5-dimensional array in C++.

Each nested vectors have known sizes so I started doing :

```
std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>> myDblVec;
```

Then assuming I know all dimension sizes :

```
myDblVec.resize(dim1);
for (int d1 = 0; d1 != dim1; d1++) {
    myDblVec[d1].resize[dim2];
    for (int d2 = 0; d2 != dim2; d2++) {
        myDblVec[d1][d2].resize(dim3)
        for (int d3 = 0; d3 != dim3; d3++) {
            myDblVec[d1][d2][d3].resize(dim4);
        }
    }
}
```

I am looking for a 1-liner or something less 'heavy' to declare this array.

Comment: I made a custom class for n-dimensional arrays that are initialized  with known sizes for each sub array. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26665096/multidimensional-array-operator-overloading/26665964#26665964

Comment: a) has the array got a fixed size? b) do you only have a small amount of data? I asked this beacuse a vector in a vector in a ... just feels .. well, wrong.

Comment: a) No, but test-wise yes b) the data is representing an image so can be quite huge. The array size would change by changing image resolution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you get the dimensions run-time, like

```
myDblVec = std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>>(dim1,
    std::vector<std::vector<std::vector<double>>>(dim2,
        std::vector<std::vector<double>>(dim3, 
            std::vector<double>>(dim4, 0.0))));
```

Comment: Nice. Any pros and cons at using this VS arrays (mostly performance wise). I know the dimensions run-time but my array/vector is part of a class definition and I only know the sizes after my class is inizialized. So I must re-declare it through some kind of `init` function.

Comment: @Julien Arrays (including `std::array`) are allocated during compilation, so the dimensions must be known at compilation time as compilation-time constants. They're also not directly allocated of the heap, so if the dimensions are large enough you can get a stack overflow very easily.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `std::array`, assuming the sizes are known at compile time:

```
std::array<std::array<std::array<std::array<double, dim4>, dim3>, dim2>, dim1> myDblArray;
```

Answer (score 1):

If you aren't too attached to pre-C++11, you could write a simple variadic template :

```
template <typename T, size_t... N> struct NestedArray;                                                                                                                                                

template <typename T, size_t N> struct NestedArray<T, N> {                                                                                                                                            
  using type = array<T, N>;                                                                                                                                                                           
};

template <typename T, size_t N, size_t... Rest>
struct NestedArray<T, N, Rest...> {
  using type = array<typename NestedArray<T, Rest...>::type, N>;
};
```

Now, you can define your array as `NestedArray<double, dim1, dim2, dim3, dim4>::type`.

Comment: Im not looking for added complexity but thx. I am new to C++ so trying to use built-in functionnality (it this makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector<T>` takes the size as first constructor argument. You could take advantage of that and use somethign along the lines of

```
make_vector_t<double, 5> myDblVec(init_vector<double, 5>(dim1, dim2, dim3, dim4, dim5));
```

That'll rquire a bit of infrastructure to create the types and initialize the elements. Of course, this infrastructure is reasonable straight forward (although I haven't compiled it - currently I'm just using a mobile device, i.e., there is almost certainly a typo somewheter but the overall approach should owrk):

```
template <typename T, int Dim> struct make_vector;
template <typename T, int Dim>
using make_vector_t = typename make_vector<T, Dim>::type;
template <typename T>
struct make_vector<T, 0> { using type = T; }
template <typename T, int Dim>
struct make_vector { using type = std::vector<make_vector_t<T, Dim-1>>; }

template <typename T, int Dim, typename Arg, typename... Args>
auto init_vector(Arg size, Args... sizes) -> make_vector_t<T, Dim-1> {
    return make_vector_t<T, Dim>(size, init_vector<T, Dim-1>(sizes...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

well... `vector<vector>` is it really a good thing? are you thinking to a matrix whose rows can have independent length? If the answer is "no", then consider the idea that all you need is a plain vector, whose size is the product of the 5 dimensions, and whose elements are located at

```
size_t at(size_t a, size_t b, size_t c, size_t d, size_t e, size_t A, size_t B, size_t C, size_t D, size_t E)
{ return e+d*E+c*D*E+b*C*D*E+a*B*C*D*E; }
```

(note: capital letters are the sizes).

You can easily generalize this to whatever number of dimensions by using varadics:

```
template<class... I>
size_t at(size_t r, size_t R, size_t c, size_t C, I... i)
{ return size_at(r*C+c,i...); }

size_t at(size_t c, size_t C)
{ return c; }
```

And you can also embed all this into a recurring class

```
template<class T, size_t Rank>
class grid
{
    grid<T,Rank-1> m; size_t C;
public:
    template<class... I>
    grid(size_t r, size_t c, I... i) :m(r*c,i...) :C(c) {}

    template<class... I>
    T& operator()(size_t r, size_t c, I... i)
    { return m(r*C+c,i...); }

    template<class... I>
    const T& operator()(size_t r, size_t c, I... i) const 
    { return m(r*C+c,i...); }
};

template<class T>
class grid<T,1>
{
    std::vector<T> m;
public:
    explicit grid(size_t n) :m(n) {}

    T& operator()(size_t i) { return m[i]; }
    const T& operator()(size_t i) const { return m[i]; }
};
```

You can just declare a `grid<5> a(3,2,4,5,3);`
and access its elements as `a(x,y,z,w,t);` whatever x in 0..2, y in 0..1, z in 0..3 w in 0..4 and t in 0..2;

Answer (score 0):

If you are in heavy need for multidimensional arrays, consider moving the stuff that has to deal with them into a separate source file that uses C instead of C++. You can interface quite easily between the languages, and allocating a 5D array of dynamical size in C is as simple as

```
double (*fiveDArray)[dim2][dim3][dim4][dim5] = malloc(dim1 * sizeof(*fiveDArray));
```

Usage is virtually the same as with your nested `std::vector<>`s, all you need to remember is the call to `free()` when you are done with your array. If you need a zero initialized array, replace `malloc()` by `calloc()`. As an added bonus, the contiguous nature of a C multidimensional array is nicer on the CPU caches than use of `std::vector<>`, and indexing is quicker since there is only one pointer to chase.

C++ does not allow this, because this language restricts array dimensions to be compile time constants. C, on the other hand, has lifted this restriction in the C99 standard, and even allows dynamic array sizes in a `typedef`:

```
void foo(size_t dim1, size_t dim2, size_t dim3, size_t dim4, size_t dim5) {
    typedef double FourDSlice[dim2][dim3][dim4][dim5];
    FourDSlice *fiveDArray = malloc(dim1 * sizeof(*fiveDArray));

    ...
}
```

is perfectly legal C99, and impossible to do in C++.